# Whitelist javascript to strip html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, strip

I have modified a whitelist javascript regex that strip unwanted tags.

I am trying to allow this code:

```
<span style="color: #000000"></span>
```

but I am unable to do it in regex.

Bellow is what is have so far:

```
(/<(?!(br|\/br|p|\/p|b|\/b|u|\/u|ol|\/ol|ul|\/ul|li|\/li))([^>])+>/gi
```

Thanks

Comment: SORRY. I didnt make myself clear. I am trying to make my regex to allow this part: style="color: #000000"

Comment: please add some examples of provided input + expected output/behaviour of the regex. Do you want to get rid of the Span tag but leave the style? or do you want to leave the tags with the content if there is a style tag inside ?

Comment: I would like to leave any of the tags with only style with color.
Allowed: <b style='color: #fffff'>, <ul style='color: #asdfgh'>, <ul>. NOT allowed: <span style='font-weight: bold'>, <span style='display: none'>, <span visible='false'>. THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me as well - unless there is more that you are trying to do - e.g. if there is any content between the tags, or if you want to match the opening and closing tag in the same run - then post the example in your question.

BTW: the regex can be simplified a little the following way:

```
<(?!((?:\/\s*)?(?:br|p|b|u|[o|i]l|li)))([^>])+>
```

- `(?:\/\s*)?` - an optional slash
- `(?:br|p|b|u|[o|i]l|li)` - followed by any of these tags

**UPDATE:**

Here's my last try:

- if you want to match all the other tags use this

  `<(?!(?:\/\s*)?(?:br|p|b|[o|u]l|li|span)(?:\s*style='color: #[A-Fa-f0-9]+'))([^>])*>`
- if you want to match the tags with color use this

  `<((?:\/\s*)?(?:br|p|b|[o|u]l|li|span)(?:\s*style='color: #[A-Fa-f0-9]+'))([^>])*>`

Comment: Please, see my comment: SORRY. I didnt make myself clear. I am trying to make my regex to allow this part: style="color: #000000"

Comment: `<(?!((?:\/\s*)?(?:br|p|b|u|[o|i]l|li|(?:span\s*style))))([^>])+>` - this would add the `span style` to the excluded tags, but not the other span tags where there is no style attribute - is that what you need?

Comment: @PasseAgora - see the update above - if that's again not what you want, I'm out of this game

Comment: This matches tags like <lii> that begin with a whitelisted tag but are something else. Use `<(?!((?:\/\s*)?(?:(br|p|b|u|[o|i]l|li)[ >]))).*?>`

Answer (score 2):

this works for me (no parenthesis at the beginning):

```
/<(?!(br|\/br|p|\/p|b|\/b|u|\/u|ol|\/ol|ul|\/ul|li|\/li))([^>])+>/gi
```

Comment: SORRY. I didnt make myself clear. I am trying to make my regex to allow this part: style="color: #000000"

Answer (score 1):

I have developed tool with Source code. It'll strip all the tags with exception list proveded by user  : try this [HTML Tag Stripper](http://htmltagstripper.com)